# Как отредактировать ячейку или столбец в csv файле?

Tags: php, csv

Подскажите как отредактировать ячейку или столбец в csv файле? средствами php

Есть csv файл с 6 строк скажем

id,найменование,цена,количество,сума

```
1,ложка,34,2,32 
2,кружка,23,4,66
3,тарелка,45,6,352 
4.вилка,21,3,235
```

скажем как перезаписать суму 34*2=

```
`


 $cart = file("data/file.csv");

  $total_sum = 0;
$summa = 0;
foreach($cart as $elem => $line)
{
    if(!strripos($line, ",")) continue;
    $elem = explode(",",$line);
    $summa += $elem[2];

  echo '<tr>
   <td>'.$elem[1].'</td>
   <td>'.$elem[2].'</td>
   <td>'.$elem[3].'</td>
   <td>'.$elem[2] * $elem[3].'</td>
   <td>'.$elem[4].'</td>
   </tr>';
}

   echo '<tr><td colspan="3" >'.$summa.'</td>
   <td>'.$total_sum.'</td><td></td></tr>';
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Прочитать csv-файл в массив, обработать необходимую ячейку массива, и перезаписать csv-файл:

```
// Искомое значение
$need = 'вилка';
// Строка для замены
$repl = 'Большая вилка';
// Путь к csv-файлу
$csv_file = 'data/file.csv';

// Новый массив с данными для записи в csv-файл
$csv_new = [];

// Если файл доступен для чтения
if (($fp = fopen($csv_file, 'r')) !== false) {
    // Читать построчно, сохраняя каждую его строку во временный массив
    while (($arr = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
        // Если найдено искомое значение
        if (($k = array_search($need, $arr)) !== false) {
            // Перезаписать ячейку массива
            $arr[$k] = $repl;
        }
        // Сохранить временный массив в новый двумерный массив
        $csv_new[] = $arr;
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

// Если файл доступен для записи
if (($fp = fopen($csv_file, 'w')) !== false) {
    // Проходим по массиву
    foreach ($csv_new as $fields) {
        // И пишем данные в csv-файл
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ , шото выводит ошибки [ ]

Comment: @PetroBoyko если интерпретатор ругается на квадратные скобки, значит версия вашего PHP ниже версии 5.4. Решить можно либо сменой версии PHP хотя бы до версии 5.4, ну или заменить сокращённые объявления массивов `$csv_new = [];` на `$csv_new = array();`

Comment: вот так пеезаписало  `1,ложка,34,2,"32 "
2,кружка,23,4,"66 "
3,тарелка,45,6,"352 "
4.вилка,21,3,"235 "`

Comment: и как с эти справится

Comment: @PetroBoyko ну да, верно. Вы почитайте об этом формате, и о работе с ним в php на [оф сайте](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: я читал уже об этом ну как это в форму разложить

Comment: @PetroBoyko копируйте пример целиком, и на его основе корректируйте код под вашу задачу. Я вместо вас её решать не буду )